# GWT - Handler for lost focus on widgets in flextable

Tags: events, gwt, listener

I'm currently coding in GWT, for the first time, and it's going well so far. I'm having a problem with EventHandlers though. I have a FlexTable which has 2 columns, 1 for labels, and 1 for TextBox/ListBox fields. When a user insert datas into the textbox  and leaves the textBox again, I want to write the contents to an object. That is quite easy, But, I can't figure out how to make the ActionHandler for it? It works fine with an OnClick event, but I want something like on focus from the FocusListener, but it's deprecated...! So what I need in a GWT, onLostFocus EventHandler of some type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `BlurHandler` over the `TextBox`. It gets called when the `TextBox` will lose the focus.

Comment: Hmm, but does that work with ListBox? I mean, what if the user use the mouse to select the ListBox element, and not TAB?

Comment: The `ListBox` is a `FocusWidget` (it wraps a native `select` element) hence he steals focus when the user interact with it, no matter how.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with valueChangeHandler on TextBox and ListBox too. Another way , you can use DomHandler on your parent widget.